# Using Google Cloud Armor with Google Cloud Endpoints - applying rate limiting and throttling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-armor

I read some documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview) on rate limiting and throttling requests to prevent attacks on Google Cloud (called Google Cloud Armor).

I have a Google Cloud Endpoints application. How do I integrate Google Cloud Armor into it? Or if not possible, how can I rate limit or throttle requests to my endpoints?

My main concern is someone flooding my endpoints with requests and then that ends up costing money as more instances are spun up.

Comment: Cloud Armor can only be attached to a load balancer. To rate limit Cloud Endpoints, review this link: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/quotas-overview

Comment: You can't easily integrate Cloud Endpoint (or API Gateway) with an HTTP Load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use Cloud Endpoints with Cloud Armor. Apigee is the API gateway to use if Cloud Armor functionality is necessary.

Cloud Armor is available for [Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/integrating-cloud-armor#serverless), [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/integrating-cloud-armor#with_ingress), [Apigee](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/api-management/api-security-with-apigee-and-google-cloud-armor), and for [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing#all-features).